# How to Remote Debug Console application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, remote-debugging

Does any know how can I remote Debug  Console application? 
With snippet I can Hold the execution process util enter into the main code but, when I attach to the process  from VS breakpoint appears not hittable.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Any(arg => arg == "debug"))
    {          
        while (!Debugger.IsAttached)
        {           
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
        Debugger.Break();
     }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's not how this works.  That's not how any of this works!

Answer (score 2):

What you are showing is not how remote debugging works.  You run an application on another machine (usually within your workgroup/domain) with the Remote Debugging tools installed on the REMOTE machine that match your version of Visual Studio.  Make sure you deploy the application compiled as DEBUG and have the symbols available on the remote computer.

Then on your local machine, you need to go to the Debug Menu --> Attach to Process and connect the debugger to the running process that you want to debug on the remote computer.  Now when the code is running and hits a breakpoint that you set locally (or exception), you'll see the debugger pause on your local computer.

MSDN:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**EDIT - Locating Symbols File:**

If you look in the location of your compiled binaries (bin folder then the compile type) and locate the file that ends in *.pdb. This contains the symbols. Make sure its in the same location as the exe on the remote computer

Comment: I'm doing it with this procedure. Remote debugger is running on remote machine and I have attached to that process. but  don't understand what you  mean for "SYmbol"!

Comment: @user6847 If you look in the location of your compiled binaries (bin folder then the compile type) and locate the file that ends in *.pdb.  This contains the symbols.  Make sure its in the same location as the exe on the remote computer.

Comment: Yes is there. I've copied the entire Debug folder on the remote machine

Comment: Since it's a console app, make sure you're connecting to the process while it's still active and BEFORE the breakpoint can be hit.  Based on your posted code, most likely the debugger isn't being attached prior to the breakpoint.  Also keep in mind that the Debugger class is marked obsolete.

Comment: As you can see, hat snippet is useful to keep live into that loop, while i'm not attached to the  process. When I do that it should go into  main code. The problem is that when I attach from VS to that process, it doesn't get out from the loop. It seems it doesn't recognize the debugger attached

Comment: Yeah don't do that because that's an obsolete class, who knows if it works anymore.  Instead do something else that blocks, like requesting input from a user on the console.  Then connect, and then hit enter or something on the console.